# Javascript: js not execute on event load

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener

I've a problem with a script that has to be executed with an event. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script  type="text/javascript" language="text/javascript">
    function isinview(obj) {
    var curleft= 0;
    var viewed=0;
    var curtop=0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
  
        do {
               curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
               curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
    scroll=document.body.scrollTop;
    screenwidth=window.innerWidth;
    screenheight=window.innerHeight;
    if (screenheight+scroll>curtop){
        var script= document.createElement('script');
        script.type= 'text/javascript';
        script.src= 'http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=1531490';
        document.getElementById("123").appendChild(script);
        viewed=1;
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" id="123" onscroll="isinview(this);">pippo
</div>
<script language="javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function(e){isinview(document.getElementById("123")); },"false");
</script>
</body>
```

Why the page doesn't execute the script on event load? I can't understand at all.

Comment: which browser are you using? old versions of IE require `window.attachEvent` instead of `window.addEventListener`

Comment: The script has been loaded but the js hasn't been executed. This is the problem..

Comment: So basically you're saying you actually want the script code in the http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=1531490 file to run? Might be worth clarifying this in your question

Comment: Exactly @TommyBs. Simplify: suppose that the script I want to run is a simple function like: 
function exec(){
console.log("executed");
}

Have I to call the function exec inside my page?

Comment: Yes if the function doesn't have a reference in the external script or is not anonymous, all the script would do is declare it not execute it. If you have access to the external script, trying changing it to something simple like: (function(){ console.log("test"); })();

Comment: @TommyBs the way you've suggested is ok. It run the function in the external script.
But I can't modify the external js. How should I call the function of the external js inside my page (after the script has been loaded)?

Comment: What's the name of the function? Just do "function_name();"

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me locally--you can verify by using `console.log` or an inline `alert`. One possible problem is that you've named an element with an id of `123`--CSS IDs can't start with a number. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: The script has been loaded but the js hasn't been executed. This is the problem..

Comment: @AlessioG That is rather odd. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using chrome and I put the page on apache. I don't run it localy.

Comment: Reduce `isinview()` to its simplest form: a single console.log or alert statement. If that executes, then your problem isn't with the event firing, it's with the body of your function. It looks like you're doing a lot of clever math with positions and visibility, so you should pay particular attention to that.

Comment: I see through chrome console (tab network) that the script has been loaded. So the problem isn't the function isinview(). I try to substitute the sript I want to be loaded with a sample script on my computer, but in this case it still hasn't been executed.

Comment: You should also verify that your browser's security settings don't prevent the execution of third-party scripts. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure what to say, then, as your basic logic seems correct, and as I said, when I execute this on my local server, it works as expected. I'd try executing this in a different environment to see if you can tease apart the various variables that could be impacting it.

Answer (score -1):

Use instead jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ isinview($("#123")); });
```

Comment: I don't want to use jquery, sorry.

Comment: Any reason to not use jQuery?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons not to use it, including: It adds a dependency that you have to manage, and page weight, for what could be a single simple use case like this. Just because you have a nice hammer doesn't mean that everything is a nail. :)

Comment: @Palpatim Well, this is one simple case in his application but I'm sure he can find a lot of others simple case (in the same application) where jQuery could be useful with a nearly insignificant extra page weight, especially when you're not developping for mobile. Now, he has to manage all cross-browsers concerns that jQuery manage so well. Actually, there are so many reasons to use jQuery than to not do so.

Comment: The OP isn't using jQuery, but suggesting to use jQuery is something could solve the problem he is facing at.

Comment: Well judging from the comments on the first post I don't think jQuery will solve this. Also I'd like to add that suggesting someone use jQuery isn't always the best answer as the OP may be trying to get a better grasp of javascript itself without resorting to a 3rd party library. This would go a long way in improving their coding, even if they did then use jQuery. An understanding of what jQuery does behind the scenes is better than just using it because you can

Comment: You're right the question wasn't clear about what script hasn't been executed and usign jQuery will not solve the problem. Personally, I think that using jQuery does not save you to know what is happening behind the scenes and therefore does not stop you to get a better grasp of javascript itself, that remain each one responsability. Thank you for your comment!